# How to get specific values from an ArrayList of HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iteration

I have created an ArrayList of HashMaps and I know how to get all keys and values of all HashMaps in the list, but then I decided to make it complicated and iterate through the ArrayList and get only specific HashMap values(based on keys). I have no idea how to do that.

How can I modify `printArrayList` method to get only `id`and `sku` values from all hashmaps?

Right now I have the following example:

```
public class HashmapArraylist {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("id", 1);
    map1.put("sku", "test1");
    map1.put("quantity", 1);

    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("id", 2);
    map2.put("sku", "test2");
    map2.put("quantity", 2);

    Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("id", 3);
    map3.put("sku", "test3");
    map3.put("quantity", 3);

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(map1);
    arrayList.add(map2);
    arrayList.add(map3);

    printArrayList(arrayList);
}

public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayList) {

    for (Map<String, Object> entry : arrayList) {
        for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
            String value = entry.get(key).toString();
            System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
        }
        System.out.println("-----------");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: No, it's not homework, as I'm trying to learn Java myself. (I even have no colleagues to help with this:) ).

I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterator for the arrayList is correct.  To retrieve a value from a map, simply provide the key into the 'get' function of the entry.  Since your map has a "String" key to an "Object" value, you can use "toString()" on it to get the string from the Object returned from your key.

```
public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayList) {

    for (Map<String, Object> entry : arrayList) {
        String myID = entry.get("id").toString();
        String mySKU = entry.get("sku").toString();
        System.out.print("id:" + myID + " sku: " + mySKU);
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user681574 seems to have already answered your problem, but I will just add one Java8 example code to do the same thing as you need, using streams

```
public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arrayList) {
    arrayList.stream() //stream out of arraylist
        .forEach(map -> map.entrySet().stream() //iterate through each map in the list, create stream out of maps' entryset
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("id") || entry.getKey().equals("sku")) //filter out only entries that we need (where key is "id" or "sku")
            .forEach(idOrSku -> System.out.println(idOrSku.getKey() + ":" + idOrSku.getValue()))); //Iterate through the id/sku entries and print them out just as we want to
}
```